# SMTP Authentication error with Gmail and Django

Tags: django, authentication, email, smtp, gmail

I have been facing an issue for a while now. I need my Django app to send password reset emails to users whenever they request for it. I have configured the SMTP correctly and even tested the connection using GMass and it seems to work fine. However, it does not work on my Django app. I have enabled 2FA and I'm using an App Password.
This is the error that it throws at me.

## SMTPAuthenticationError at /reset_password/

```
`(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z7-20020a7bc7c7000000b003fee567235bsm21423680wmk.1 - gsmtp')
```

Request Method:POSTRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset_password/Django Version:4.2.5Exception Type:SMTPAuthenticationErrorException Value:(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z7-20020a7bc7c7000000b003fee567235bsm21423680wmk.1 - gsmtp')Exception Location:C:\Users\perfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py, line 662, in authRaised during:django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetViewPython Executable:C:\Users\perfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exePython Version:3.11.5Python Path:['F:\\Python Learning\\Projects\\crm', 'C:\\Users\\perfa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip', 'C:\\Users\\perfa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\perfa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\perfa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311', 'C:\\Users\\perfa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages']Server time:Thu, 12 Oct 2023 09:52:40 +0000

Here is my SMTP config `

```
`#SMTP Configuration

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'pe#######@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'm############'`
```

Sorry I had to hide my email and password for security reasons. I have tried testing the SMTP configs on GMASS and it worked but the same configs do not work on my code. If the configuration works on my code, I expect it to send users password reset emails using my email address.